# PHP Datetime: How to get first and last hour of the day?

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

In PHP `\DateTime` or `Carbon`, it is easy to do things like `new \DateTime('first day of last month');` or `new \DateTime('last day of last month')`, I want to know whether there is something similar like `first hour of last day` and `last hour of last day`? The existing code for Month and week look like the below, I need to do it at the day level and assign these variable accordingly:

```
if ($this->monthWeekSelect === 'month') {
    $this->lastMonthFirstDay = new \DateTime('first day of last month');
    $this->lastMonthLastDay = new \DateTime('last day of last month');
    $this->currentMonthFirstDay = new \DateTime('first day of this month');
    $this->currentMonthLastDay = new \DateTime('last day of this month');
    $this->oneMonthFirstDay = new \DateTime('first day of +1 month');
    $this->oneMonthLastDay = new \DateTime('last day of +1 month');
    $this->twoMonthFirstDay = new \DateTime('first day of +2 month');
    $this->twoMonthLastDay = new \DateTime('last day of +2 month');
    $this->threeMonthFirstDay = new \DateTime('first day of +3 month');
    $this->threeMonthLastDay = new \DateTime('last day of +3 month');
} else { // For Week
    $this->lastMonthFirstDay = new \DateTime('monday last week');
    $this->lastMonthLastDay = new \DateTime('sunday last week');
    $this->currentMonthFirstDay = new \DateTime('monday this week');
    $this->currentMonthLastDay = new \DateTime('sunday this week');
    $this->oneMonthFirstDay = (new Carbon('monday this week'))->addWeek(1);
    $this->oneMonthLastDay = (new Carbon('sunday this week'))->addWeek(1);
    $this->twoMonthFirstDay = (new Carbon('monday this week'))->addWeek(2);
    $this->twoMonthLastDay = (new Carbon('sunday this week'))->addWeek(2);
    $this->threeMonthFirstDay = (new Carbon('monday this week'))->addWeek(3);
    $this->threeMonthLastDay = (new Carbon('sunday this week'))->addWeek(3);
}
```

Comment: Well, have you looked in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) about what tokens it understands? Have you tried it out? If not you'd have to come up with your own algorithm to calculate it. It's not clear what point in the research you're starting from.

Comment: Wouldn't the first hour be 0 and the last hour be 23 for every day?

Comment: @ADyson Yes I did but since I am new so was struggling how to format, I will try again

Comment: @brombeer yes and I can add/subtract date too, was wondering how to do it using `DateTime` or `Carbon ` library

Answer (score 3):

Times can be written together with relative date expressions.

```
$lastHourCurrentDay = date_create('today 23:00');  //or new DateTime('today 23:00');
$firstHourCurrentDay = date_create('today');  //or 'today 00:00'
$lastHourYesterday = new DateTime('Yesterday 23:00');
```